# z3Py: Cast BoolRef to one-bit BitVecRef

Tags: python, casting, z3, z3py, bitvector

Is it possible to cast `BoolRef` to a one-bit-long `BitVecRef` in z3Py? In my design, it is required that a `BitVecRef` is returned from a comparison between two other `BitVecRef`'s. This would be similar to casting a python `bool` to an `int`. Here is an example of its use:

```
bv1, bv2, added = z3.BitVecs('bv1 bv2 added', 4)
res = z3.BitVec('res', 1)
s = z3.Solver()
s.add(res == (bv1 < bv2))
s.add(added == added + z3.ZeroExt(3, res))
```

This would be ideal, but the type of `(bv1 < bv2)` is `Boolref`, and it throws a "sort mismatch" error. Is there a way to cast the result of `(bv1 < bv2)` so that `res` can asserted equal to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit-vectors can't be casted to Boolean automatically. The usual approach is to wrap them in if-then-elses, e.g., in this example, instead of

```
s.add(res == (bv1 < bv2))
```

we can say

```
c = If(bv1 < bv2, BitVecVal(1, 1), BitVecVal(0, 1))
s.add(res == c)
```